# How do I add an image to my application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, image, window

I want to change the background of the main window in my WPF application.

I have read around a lot of questions, and they all talk about adding with image tag, or assigning from resources, etc etc.

But no one actually shows how to actually get that image into the application so that it can used.

I imagine it has to be packed into the application somehow because if you send the exe to someone and you have an image tag which points to a folder on your computer locally, then they wont have that same folder or image file on theres necessarily, so how do you actually add the image in to the project, seems crazy or i might be looking in the wrong places that there is no easy or clear cut way to do this. and then use that to change the background of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select an `ImageBrush` as the window's Background Property

```
 <Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/IMAG0231.jpg" />
</Window.Background>
```

So select the `Window` and press F4. Go to the Brushes part and select `Background` the chose the `ImageBrush` and select your image.

[image]

Comment: I go to brush, and then image brush, and again, it just shows an image source box, which has an empty drop down. still doesnt answer the fact i want to know how to get an image in there so i can select it.

Comment: find the `Select image` button

Comment: My screen looks completely different. im using 2013 if that helps

Comment: Ok, create a folder in your solution (e.g. `Images`) then add any image to that folder (e.g. `Image01.jpg`) then right click on that image and set it's build action to `Resource`. then in your XAML code reference it like this: `ImageSource="/YOURSOLUTIONNAME;component/Images/Image01.jpg:`

Comment: Added folder, but never saw the images folder appear in solution explorer so cant right click the image.

Comment: Also, you say go to the brushes part, i dont have that, i only have Brush, without the es

Comment: Huh? I tried that also, but wheni tried to add the image to that folder it just wouldnt let me.

Comment: 1. Right click on the project in solution explorer->Add->New Folder

Comment: 2. Right click on the folder->Add ->existing item->change the filter to All files then select your image

Comment: 3. You can see the brushes part in the picture. If not, its not important look at the XAML in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps please
Select the window -> go to properties window -> select background -> click Add -> click Ok 
now your  image is in the resource applications  it will works fine even with 2013

[image]

Comment: I dont see what you do. when i click my window, in the properties box, i get the following categories: Brush, Appearance, common, layout, text, misc.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop the image in to one of your project folders in Visual Studio.